# Looping collection to jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, charts, morris.js

I have static chart with jquery and i want to use dynamic data in it but it returns `SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'`

## code

`Static`

```
Morris.Area({
  element: 'dashboard-area-1',
  data: [
    { y: '2014-10-10', a: 17,b: 19, c: 10},
    { y: '2014-10-11', a: 19,b: 21, c: 11},
    { y: '2014-10-12', a: 22,b: 25, c: 33},
    { y: '2014-10-13', a: 20,b: 22, c: 55},
    { y: '2014-10-14', a: 21,b: 24, c: 89},
    { y: '2014-10-15', a: 34,b: 37, c: 34},
    { y: '2014-10-16', a: 43,b: 45, c: 65}
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a','b', 'c'],
  labels: ['Page', 'Visitors','Page Views'],
  resize: true,
  hideHover: true,
  xLabels: 'day',
  gridTextSize: '10px',
  lineColors: ['#1caf9a','#33414E', '#2344d3'],
  gridLineColor: '#E5E5E5'
});
```

`Dynamic`

```
var analysdata = "{{$analyticsData}}";
Morris.Area({
  element: 'dashboard-area-1',
  data: [
    $.each( analysdata, function( key, value ) {
      y: '2014-10-10', a: value.pageTitle,b: value.visitors, c: value.pageViews,
    });
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a','b', 'c'],
  labels: ['Page', 'Visitors','Page Views'],
  resize: true,
  hideHover: true,
  xLabels: 'day',
  gridTextSize: '10px',
  lineColors: ['#1caf9a','#33414E', '#2344d3'],
  gridLineColor: '#E5E5E5'
});
```

error comes from:

```
y: '2014-10-10', a: value.pageTitle,b: value.visitors, c: value.pageViews,
```

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you need this:

```
return view( 'your_view_name',[ 
    'analyticsData'=> json_encode($analyticsData, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES ); 
]);
```

Then, try this:

```
var analysdata = {!! $analyticsData !!};
const theData = [];
$.each( analysdata, function( key, value ) {
    theData.push({
        y: '2014-10-10', a: value.pageTitle,b: value.visitors, c: value.pageViews
    });
});

Morris.Area({
    element: 'dashboard-area-1',
    data: theData,
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a','b', 'c'],
    labels: ['Page', 'Visitors','Page Views'],
    resize: true,
    hideHover: true,
    xLabels: 'day',
    gridTextSize: '10px',
    lineColors: ['#1caf9a','#33414E', '#2344d3'],
    gridLineColor: '#E5E5E5'
});
```

Comment: giving `TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got string`

Comment: it refers to `$.each( analysdata, function( key, value ) {`

Comment: Ah, I thought `"{{$analyticsData}}"` was just a placeholder  your your analytics object - it's just set to a string? Where does the data actually come from?

Comment: from controller thats returning my dynamic data as collection :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186917/discussion-between-markmoxx-and-mafortis).

Comment: Have you checked the chat, and seen my updated answer?

Comment: unfortunately no, i shared my answer in discussion

Comment: we fixed `the SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'` though?